# Rectangular Pulse Shaping

Tags: digital-communications

Why is not doing any pulse shaping of a sequence of digital data  equivalent to a rectangular pulse shaping (as mentioned in some texts)?

I kind of see that no pulse shaping is rather equivalent to rectangular windowing of the whole sequence of data and that is not filtering (to my understanding at least)
Can someone help me understand this issue please?

Comment: If you're working with digital signals, you're only dealing with 0 and 1, assuming with negligible delay in transition. You get a rectangular pulse for that as there are no other states involved except 0 and 1.

Comment: This question is pretty meaningless: The answer is: it mathematically is equivalent. Have you tried writing down and maybe drawing what rectangular pulse shaping means? If so, where did you encounter problems? I'm trying to figure out where to help you here, because it's not clear from your question where you're stuck, what you *don't* understand.

Comment: I am trying to understand the issue conceptually. Pulse shaping is filtering and filtering is convolution in time domain, why would a time limited stream of data be mathematically equivalent for that stream to be convolved with a rectangular pulse?

Comment: It might be useful to excerpt or link to a few of those texts you speak of.